# What does it mean when JSON from jest coverage have null as column?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, elisp, ts-jest

I'm trying to run my Emacs Lisp code on Code Coverage from jest with TypeScript and it fails because the file (`/coverage/coverage-final.json`) that I use to read coverage that has an invalid (according to my code) data.

This is my code to be complete:

```lisp
(defun jc/mark-buffer-jest ()
  (interactive)
  (message "jc/mark-buffer-jest")
  (let* ((dir (jc/root-git-repo))
         (json-object-type 'hash-table)
         (json-array-type 'list)
         (json-key-type 'string)
         (coverage-fname (concat dir "/coverage/coverage-final.json")))
    (if (not (file-exists-p coverage-fname))
        (message "file coverage not found")
      (let* ((json (json-read-file coverage-fname))
             (filename (jc/real-filename (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))))
             (coverage (gethash filename json)))
        (if (not (hash-table-p coverage))
            (message "No coverage found for this file")
          (let ((statments (gethash "statementMap" coverage)))
            (save-excursion
              (let ((coverage-list (gethash "s" coverage))
                    (covered 0)
                    (not-covered 0))
                (maphash (lambda (key value)
                           (if (not (and jc/statements (= (gethash key jc/statements) value)))
                               (let* ((statment (gethash key statments))
                                      (start (gethash "start" statment))
                                      (end (gethash "end" statment))
                                      (start-line-pos (jc/line-pos-at-line (gethash "line" start)))
                                      (start-pos (+ start-line-pos (gethash "column" start)))
                                      (end-line-pos (jc/line-pos-at-line (gethash "line" end)))
                                      (end-pos (+ end-line-pos (gethash "column" end)))
                                      (face (if (= value 0)
                                                'jc/not-covered
                                              'jc/covered)))
                                 (message "[%s:%s] %s:%s -> [%s:%s] %s:%s"
                                          (gethash "line" start)
                                          (gethash "column" start)
                                          start-line-pos start-pos
                                          (gethash "line" end)
                                          (gethash "column" end)
                                          end-line-pos end-pos)
                                     (hlt-highlight-region start-pos end-pos face)))
                           (if (= value 0)
                               (setq not-covered (+ 1 not-covered))
                             (setq covered (+ 1 covered))))
                         coverage-list)
                (message "%3.2f%% coverage" (* (/ (float covered) (+ covered not-covered)) 100))
                (setq jc/statements coverage-list)))))))))
```

It throw an error:

> (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)

In this line:

```lisp
(end-pos (+ end-line-pos (gethash "column" end)))
```

The reason for this is that some of the statements look like this:

```
"24":{"start":{"line":70,"column":4},"end":{"line":72,"column":null}}
```

What does it mean that column is null? Is the content of this JSON documented somewhere? I run my code on a TypeScript file with ts-jest.